# How to get images field from a Group Feed - Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been using Graph API for a while, but I am not able to figure this one out. 
I have a group id, from whose feed I want to get the image urls for all available resolutions.

I know I can do that using the 'images' field of a photo id. 
Here is a sample code which gets the id

```
<group-id>/feed?fields=attachments{target{id}}
```

I tried

```
<group-id>/feed?fields=attachments{target{id{images}}}
```

and also this

```
<group-id>/feed?fields=attachments.fields(target.fields(id{images}))
```

and this

```
<group-id>/feed?fields=attachments.fields(target.fields(id.fields(images)))
```

All of them return the JSON having the id, but not the images details I need.

I hope I have provided enough information.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below format while calling the API and it will return you with the images URL included in the post

```
<group-id>/feed?fields=created_time,attachments,message
```

You  will get the response in the below format.

```
{
      "created_time": "2017-11-16T06:21:37+0000",
      "id": "543993212434753_1004360179731385",
      "attachments": {
        "data": [
          {
            "description": "Best #ethnic wear store for #women.
Shop Now>> sairandhri.com",
            "media": {
              "image": {
                "height": 720,
                "src": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/23519069_887109751445971_6170575397465061641_n.jpg?oh=170436ae447ec615f547d700017c67b4&oe=5AA4F844",
                "width": 537
              }
            },
            "target": {
              "id": "887109751445971",
              "url": "https://www.facebook.com/SairandhriShowroom/photos/a.302015823288703.1073741828.300462640110688/887109751445971/?type=3"
            },
            "type": "photo",
            "url": "https://www.facebook.com/SairandhriShowroom/photos/a.302015823288703.1073741828.300462640110688/887109751445971/?type=3"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Its working and tested on Graph API Explorer